# Jolt : Concat of 7th and 8th position value in file

Tags: json, jolt

Input:

```json
[
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "PAFrstNm": "John"
  },
  {
    "PALastNm": "Jammy",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "PAMiNm": "T",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "PPFrstNm": "sam"
  },
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "PPLastNm": "jim"
  },
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "PPMiNm": "E"
  },
  {
    "policy": "Name",
    "PPFrstNm1": "jun"
  },
  {
    "policy": "Other",
    "Summer": "533A"
  },
  {
    "policy": "Other",
    "Winter": "588A"
  },
  {
    "PPLastNm1": "san",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "PPMiNm1": "e",
    "policy": "Name"
  }
]
```

Ouput needed:

```json
[
  {
    "PAfullnam": "John T Jammy",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "PPfullnam": "sam E jim",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "PPfullnam1": "jun e san",
    "policy": "Name"
  },
  {
    "Session": "533A 588A ",
    "policy": "Other"
  }
]
```

Jolt spec tried:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "LastN|FrstN|MiN": "@1,policy.&(0,1)fullna&(0,2)"
          // the order of the part above is not important 
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "0|2|1": "&2.&1.[#1]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ful": "=join(' ',@(1,&))",
        "Session": "=concat(@(1,Summer),' ',@(1,Winter))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[#2].&",
          "$1": "[#2].policy"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan, please do the needful

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan...just one query ,what would teh changes for teh below scenarios.
concat= PPLastNm1+PPMiNm1+PPLastNm1
concat= PPLastNm+PPMiNm+PPLastNm
concat=PAFrstNm+PAMiNm+PALastname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with adding new key-value pair into the first spec :

```json
        "*er": "@1,policy.SWfullname"
```

proper to Wint**er** and Summ**er** and go on like this :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*LastN*|*FrstN*|*MiN*": "@1,policy.&(0,1)fullna&(0,2)",
        "*er": "@1,policy.SWfullname"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "0|2|1": "&2.&1.[#1]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=join(' ',@(1,&))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&2_&1.&",
          "$1": "&2_&1.policy"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  }
]
```